# Casting of self-referencing entities, detect generic type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Once, I got an interface for all entities:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

For some entities a mutationtable will exist, to log, what was done for which entity (CRUD)

```
public interface IMutation<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity
{
    ICollection<Mutation<TEntity>> Mutations { get; set; }
}
```

For each entity that implements `IMutation` Entity Framework will create a table with name `Mutation<EntityName>`
So, `Mutation<EntityName>` is an entity, too.

```
public class Mutation<TEntity> : Entity where TEntity : IEntity
{
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public TEntity Entity { get; set; }
}
```

I implemented the interface `IEntity` on a class, that some entities will inherit.

```
public class Entity : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

The entity `Test` inherits from `Entity` (becuase it's an entity) and implements IMutation with a reference to itself

```
public class Test : Entity, IMutation<Test>
{
    public ICollection<Mutation<Test>> Mutations { get; set; } = new List<Mutation<Test>>();
}
```

Entity Framework gets it, and creates the two tables:

- `Test` with properties `Id` and `Name`
- `Mutation<Test>` with property `Id` (the PK from `IEntity`) and `EntityId` (the FK referencing the `Test`-entity)

this all works great. DB-schema and so on.

So what I want to do is, always, when one entity taht implements `IMutation<EntityName>` is changed, a new dataset shall be created.
There is the possibility to override `SaveChanges` of DbContext. Nice, so I tried it:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    IEnumerable<EntityEntry> entries = ChangeTracker.Entries(); // gets me all entries that were changed

    IEnumerable<IEntity> mutationEntries =
        entries.Select(s => s.Entity).Where(
            w =>
                w.GetType()
                    .GetInterfaces()
                    .Any(
                        x =>
                            x.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMutation<>)))
                            .Select(s => (IEntity)s);

    // so here now I got the entries that implement IMutation<?> <-- call this now ?-type
    // what I'd now want to do is:
    foreach(var entry in mutationEntries)
    {
        IMutation<?> mutationEntry = (IMutation<?>)entry;
        mutationEntry.Mutations.Add(new Mutation<?>{ /* later on, add here CRUD, Id, user who changed,... */ });
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem now is, that I never know, what my ?-Type is. I know it has to be from Type `IEntity`. 
But when I try to parse the Entity to `IMutation<IEntity>` i get an error, saying, he cannot cast from `IMutation<Test>` to `IMutation<IEntity>`. (But `Test` implements `IEntity`)

Tried it this way:

```
IEnumerable<IMutation<IEntity>> mutationEntries =
        entries.Select(s => s.Entity).Where(
            w =>
                w.GetType()
                    .GetInterfaces()
                    .Any(
                        x =>
                            x.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMutation<>)))
                            .Select(s => (IMutation<IEntity>)s);
```

But I'm already checking, whether my Entity implements `IMutation`. 
Maybe someone has an idea, how I could solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to work with generic interfaces that are not covariant and have no non generic counterparts (like `IEnumerable<T>` -> `IEnumerable`, `IQueryable<T>` -> `IQueryable` etc.).

The only remaining choice in such case is reflection or dynamic dispatch.

For instance, you could add a method like this:

```
private void ProcessMutationEntity<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
    where TEntity : IEntity, IMutation<TEntity>
{
    entity.Mutations.Add(new Mutation<TEntity> { EntityId = entity.Id, Entity = entity});
}
```

and then use DLR to call it (using the code from the first example):

```
// ...
foreach (var entry in mutationEntries)
{
    ProcessMutationEntity((dynamic)entry);
}
// ...
```

Comment: Please, change your ProcessMutationEntity-Function to `private void ProcessMutationEntity<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : IEntity, IMutation<TEntity> { entity.Mutations.Add(new Mutation<TEntity> { EntityId = entity.Id, Entity = entity}); }` - you are a genious, man! It finally works. You saved me for sure 5 more hours.

Comment: Here you go:) Glad that helped. Cheers.